# Does CloudFlare caches my jQuery logic?

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I have a question and I don't have a server with cloudflare in order to test this, hope someone could help me.

I have an html page with a jQuery logic for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script src="timer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

timer.js

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
});
function myFunction() {
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
    $('#demo').html(time);   
}
```

as we know Cloudflare caches JS and HTML content but my jQuery is a timer that will show the time each time I send a response.

What would happen with CloudFlare if I had Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000 and Cloudflare caches everything.

is my jQuery logic going to work? or  is the timer going to stop working ?

I am using a timer in this example but my real jQuery logic what it does is to hide some DIV content randomly, I have a website where I have like 5 rows this rows are always there but with jQuery I remove ($target.remove()) some of them randomly and the others I just shuffle them.

but I'd like to know if my logic will still working ? or my jQuery will continue as normal?

Answer (score 2):

CloudFlare doesn't execute your JavaScript, it just caches it. If your script modifies the DOM in a user's browser, CloudFlare won't cache that.